# What's a good way to create waist elastic band on pants?

Tags: modeling, mesh

I'm working on a pair of cargo pants in blender, as shown in the image below. I wanted to ask what's a good way to maybe maybe the selected bits on the pants emulate an elastic band (also pictured for reference.

Thank you

[image: Text]

[image: Text]

Comment: Does it have to be a part if the model (topology), or can it be done by material (shader)?

Comment: @ChristopherBennett, preferable model, but I'm open to other ideas

Comment: If you want to do it for the model, I would suggest sculpting.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can get fairly close with this kind of approach. Totally procedural, aside from modelling the initial segment.

Add a cylinder, give it like 64 sides, no end caps, give it a fair amount of vertical edge rings, enough so that each individual poly is basically a perect square. then turn it on it's side, and scale it to where it's tall and skinny on the Y-axis, something like this. Then pull in two of these edge loops to serve as the seam. Its also probably possible to do this with a single curve and then extrude it, loft it etc. I just went with what was easy.

[image]

Then add a subsurf with one or two levels of divisions. Followed by an Array modifier with however many instances you want (this depends on your project and use case). Make sure to set the vertices to *Merge*.

[image]

Add a Displace modifier, set to use a texture. Go to the texture editor and use a Wood texture, which gives you a bunch of different kinds of sine wave functions. Change the *Pattern* to Band Noise. We want the size of this one to be kind of big. Something like these values worked for me.

[image]

Then duplicate that displace modifier, duplicate it's texture too, by clicking this button in the texture editor.

[image]

Increase the distortion, and make the waves a bit smaller, about twice as small as the previous texture, something like this.

[image]

In both of these displace modifiers you'll want to set the coordinates to Object. Then add an empty and you can use that to easily control the alignment and size of the noise.

[image]

Then I added a Simple Deform Bend, just to put it into a ring shape. You could also use curve deform or something like that for a more organic shape.

Result:

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. I got almost what I wanted. I just have this issue where my mesh looks like this. https://imgur.com/a/D9Rwirw. Do you know what I'm doing wrong

Comment: Actually, I was able to sort of fix this by turning down the strength of the displace modifiers wayyy down. Thank you

Comment: Yeah, sorry I guess I went super detailed with everything except the Displace settings. You figured it out though! Glad to help!.